# Global hook of WM_APPCOMMAND (appcommand_media_play, appcommand_media_stop etc)

Tags: delphi, global, keyboard-hook

I am trying to capture [`WM_APPCOMMAND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-appcommand) messages in my Delphi application (e.g. `APPCOMMAND_MEDIA_PLAY`, `APPCOMMAND_MEDIA_STOP`,  `APPCOMMAND_MEDIA_NEXTTRACK`)

Currently I'm using the code:

```
procedure WMAppCommand(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_APPCOMMAND;

procedure TForm1.WMAppCommand;
begin
   case (msg.LParamHi AND NOT FAPPCOMMAND_MASK) of
   APPCOMMAND_MEDIA_PLAY: play;
   APPCOMMAND_MEDIA_PAUSE: pause;
   APPCOMMAND_MEDIA_STOP: stop;
   APPCOMMAND_MEDIA_NEXTTRACK: next;
   APPCOMMAND_MEDIA_PREVIOUSTRACK: prev;
   end;
   inherited;
end;
```

but this works only when the window has focus.

I think good way to do this may be windows hook ex, but i dont know how to capture these special keys with it. Moreover, I never wrote a library which is required to make global hook.

Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Comment: My guess is that the `RegisterHotkey` winapi function is what you need.